# How do chat servers distribute messages to multiple clients?

Tags: python, sockets, design-patterns, server, chat

This is really a programming design question more than a specific language or library question. I'm tinkering with the idea of a standalone chat server for websockets that will accept several remote browser-based javascript clients. I'm going for something super simple at first, then might build it up. The server just keeps accepting client connections and listens for messages. When a message is received, it will be sent back to all the clients.

What I need to better understand is which approach is best for sending the messages out to all clients, specifically, sending immediately to all clients, or queuing the messages to each client's queue to be sent when a client connection handler's turn comes up. Below are the two examples in a python-like pseudo-code:

**Broadcast Method**

```
def client_handler(client):
    while true:
        if(client.pending_msg):
            rmsg = client.recv()
            for c in clients:
                c.send(rmsg)
        client.sleep(1)
```

**Queue Method**

```
def client_handler(client):
    while true:
        if client.pending_msg:
            rmsg = client.recv()
            for c in clients:
                c.queue_msg(rmsg)
        if client.has_queued:
            client.send_queue
        client.sleep(1)
```

What is the best approach? Or, perhaps they are good for different use-cases, in which case, what are the pros, cons and circumstances for which they should be used. Thanks!

Comment: Best thing that comes to my mind is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems odd to me that a single client handler would know about all the other existing clients. This should be the first thing you should abstract away and create a central message processing handler instead which the individual clients talk to.

That handler can then either send the message directly to the clients (like in your broadcast example), or add them to queues of the clients (like your queue example). Which would be the preferred version depends a bit on your network protocol.

Since you said that you will be using websockets, you have a persistent network connection to the clients anyway, so you can just send them out immediately. There is no real gain to queue (and buffer) the messages. Ideally, a client would just have a `send()` method anyway, and the client would then internally decide whether that means appending it to a queue or sending it immediately over the network.

Furthermore, since websockets are kind of asynchronous in their nature, you don’t need busy wait loops anyway. You can just listen for messages from the client directly, process those, and broadcast them using your central handler. And since you then don’t have a wait loop anymore, there also would be no place where you work off your queue anymore, making the immediate broadcast the more natural decision.